# Какие есть варианты решения: composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed? (QWebEnginewidget, QDockWidget)

Tags: qt5, qwebengineview, qdockwidget

Всем привет. Столкнулся со странной ошибкой, которую не понимаю.
Использую:

- Windows10
- Qt 5.15.2
- QWebEngineView
- QDockWidget

Ошибка заключается в следующем: окно WebEngine инициализированное внутри DockWidget работает только внутри этого док виджета, если его вынести за пределы основного окна - оно перестает отображать информацию и пишет ошибку:
**(qt.qpa.backingstore) - composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed**
Если поместить виджет обратно в Dock, то он начинает показывать

Обратная ситуация происходит и при инициализации окна вне Dock: Если инициализировать окно вне Dock, то оно показывает нормально до тех пор, пока не всунешь его в Dock, а там он вообще ломается

- Драйвера GPU обновлены

p.s. Попробовал на Ubuntu20.04 - такой ошибки нет

Comment: а есть минимальный рабочий вариант?

Comment: Минимальный рабочий вариант работает исправно.
На то и он и минимальный. 
А воспроизвести такое поведение не получается.
Мб есть какие-нибудь, назовем их "Вехи", на которые стоит обратить внимание?